# No WordPress.com blog or external site feed found at the supplied URL

Tags: wordpress

I'm attempting to add an external blog to my Wordpress.com account for the site www.civilbeat.com and getting the error:

> No WordPress.com blog or external site feed found at the supplied URL

Does this require adding the RSS feed url here or something misconfigured with how the feed is being requested?

[image]

No WordPress.com blog or external site feed found at the supplied URL

Comment: Try `http://www.civilbeat.com/feed/`.

Comment: Hey I actually tried exactly that and am getting the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

From timethief on Wordpress.com:

> The My Blogs section of your WordPress.COM Dashboard lists the
>   WordPress.COM blogs that you can contribute to and/or edit.
>   https://en.support.wordpress.com/my-blogs/
>
> That's not where you enter blogs that you follow at all. You do that
>   here https://wordpress.com/following/edit/

My issue was that I was attempting to add the blog to the My Blogs section instead of Blogs I Follow section.